# How to Create a report in SSRS using Flat file source?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2, msbi

I got the requirement from one of my client to create ssrs reports using Flat file source in SSDT 2012. For my understanding to create SSRS report using flat file there is no direct method.We need to change the flat file source to other source(EX: Excel,Oledb Etc..) which is supported by Microsoft SSRS.

Now my question is is there any possibility to create Report using direct flat file connection in ssrs?

Thanks in Advance

PPras'd

Comment: At last i got the answer for this question :)

Comment: I just checked and you create data sources of type OLE DB and ODBC, and I believe both be set up to reference text files, but I don't know what SQL Syntax they support. So why don't you try OLE DB for starters. You can find sample connection strings on the internet. The text file needs to be accessible from the report server via the service account, i.e. the text file cannot be sitting on the users PC. I don't think your client has considered that.

Comment: Nick.McDermaid i was got the answer for the question any refrence please visit my blog   http://bpnmsbi.blogspot.in/

Comment: Yes, like I said use an ODBC or OLE DB connection. You can probably also use ODBC without needing to create an actual DSN. Also keep in mind you won't be able to join to other tables.